# How to compare three cards in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling

I am attempting to modify a memory game and match three cards when selected. However I don't seem to be able to select the third card thus my matchThreeCards function is not working. Should I use a different approach in loading and checking which card is selected? Any recommendations?. Hope this code is readable enough for you to understand.

**My script**

```
var cardFront = document.createElement("div");
var gameOneButton = document.querySelector("#gameOneButton");
var gameTwoButton = document.querySelector("#gameTwoButton");
var gameThreeButton = document.querySelector("#gameThreeButton");
var gameBoard = document.querySelector(".gameBoard");

let hasCard = false;
let cardOne, cardTwo, cardThree, cardFour;
let match = document.getElementById("modalContainer");
// game1Array = [];

class Card {
  constructor(bacface) {
    this.backface = bacface;
  }

  newCard() {
    var card = document.createElement("div"); //data attribute
    card.className = "card";
    card.setAttribute("data-color", this.backface);

    var cardFront = document.createElement("div");
    cardFront.className = "cardFront";

    var cardBack = document.createElement("div");
    cardBack.className = this.backface;

    card.appendChild(cardFront);
    card.appendChild(cardBack);

    gameBoard.append(card); //addcards
    card.addEventListener("click", cardFlip);
  }
}


cardGreen = new Card("cardGreen");
cardBlue = new Card("cardBlue");
cardYellow = new Card("cardYellow");
cardPink = new Card("cardPink");
cardBlack = new Card("cardBlack");
cardOrange = new Card("cardOrange");
cardPurple = new Card("cardPurple");
cardGray = new Card("cardGray");
cardDarkRed = new Card("cardDarkRed");
cardCyan = new Card("cardCyan");
cardDarkBlue = new Card("cardDarkBlue");
cardBrown = new Card("cardBrown");


var basicMode = [cardGreen, cardBlue,  cardYellow, cardPink, cardGray, cardBlack,
                  cardGreen, cardBlue,  cardYellow, cardPink, cardGray, cardBlack,
];

var enhancedMode = [cardGreen, cardGreen,  cardGreen, cardPink, cardGray, cardBlack,
                     cardGreen, cardBlue,  cardYellow, cardPink, cardGray, cardBlack,
                     cardOrange, cardPurple, cardDarkRed, cardCyan, cardDarkBlue, cardBrown,
                     cardOrange, cardPurple, cardDarkRed, cardCyan, cardDarkBlue, cardBrown,
];


gameOneButton.addEventListener("click", renderEasyMode);
gameTwoButton.addEventListener("click", renderEasyMode);

function renderEasyMode(e) {
  if (e.target == gameOneButton) {
    basicMode.forEach(card => card.newCard());
  } else if (e.target == gameTwoButton) {
    enhancedMode.forEach(card => card.newCard());
}
  gameBoard.style.display = "grid";
  gameOneButton.removeEventListener("click",renderEasyMode);
  gameTwoButton.removeEventListener("click",renderEasyMode);
}

function cardFlip() {
  this.classList.add("flip");
  if (!hasCard) {
    hasCard = true; //set when first card is clicked
    cardOne = this;

  } else if (cardOne){
    hasCard = false; //set when second card is clicked
    cardTwo = this;

  } else if(cardOne && cardTwo){
    hasCard =true;
    cardThree = this;
    console.log(this)

    matchThreeCards();

  }
}

function matchThreeCards() {
  //match Cards
  if (cardOne.dataset.color === cardTwo.dataset.color === cardThree.dataset.color) {
    cardOne.removeEventListener("click", cardFlip);
    cardTwo.removeEventListener("click", cardFlip);
    cardThree.removeEventListener("click", cardFlip);

    match.style.display = "flex";
    setTimeout(removeCards, 2000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      //Time out is used for space in between button clicks
      cardOne.classList.remove("flip");
      cardTwo.classList.remove("flip");
      cardThree.classList.remove("flip");
    }, 1500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
cardOne.dataset.color === cardTwo.dataset.color === cardThree.dataset.color
```

is evaluated as

```
(cardOne.dataset.color === cardTwo.dataset.color) === cardThree.dataset.color
```

which is either

```
true === cardThree.dataset.color
```

or

```
false === cardThree.dataset.color
```

and always returns false in your case, because `cardThree.dataset.color` is neither `true` nor `false`.

You can compare three values with

```
cardOne.dataset.color === cardTwo.dataset.color && cardTwo.dataset.color === cardThree.dataset.color
```

Example:

```js
const a = 3;
const b = 3;
const c = 3;
const d = 4;

console.log(a === b === c);
console.log(a === b && b === c);
console.log(a === b && b === d);
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But the real issue I am having is getting the third click event. I then want to compare it to the first two. I think I should keep the first first two results in a variable if they match and then compare to third click. I just not wrapping my head how to go about this

Comment: Sory to take this long in replying @jabba

Comment: @abtrini It looks like your question is either unclear, too broad or requires debugging details. You've registered an event listener for the card click. This listener should be triggered. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: @abtrini Why do you set `hasCard = false;` in the `else if` block

Comment: @abtrini Just do explain why your question is unclear or too broad: Your question is _"How to compare three cards in javascript"_ and know you're asking how to click a third card. That's two different things.

Comment: Thanks for he assistance. I modified the question.

Comment: You are correct I am asking how to click a third card. When the third card is located I would like to compare it to the previous two cards data-set for a match.

Comment: @abtrini That sounds like a completely different question. Please don't modify questions after they were answered in a way it invalidates the answers. Ask a new question.